# Weblogic deployment using ant tasks

Tags: ant, weblogic, wlst

I came to know that weblogic provides some ant tasks to deploy our application with build.xml. I need to create a weblogic user for existing domain whenever I deploy the application into my one of the server instances. Is there any task available into WLserver to achieve this?? Please give me some suggestions for this.
Code snippets are highly appreciable.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

WLST is the way to go for this.  See [Using the WebLogic Scripting Tool](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28280_01/web.1111/e13715/using_wlst.htm#WLSTG118) for details on calling this from Ant and [WLST Command and Variable Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28280_01/web.1111/e13813/reference.htm#WLSTC119) for command details, but below is a sample build.xml and wlst script to create a group, a user and add the user to the group.

build.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252" ?>
<project default="create_user">

  <property environment="env"/>

  <path id="wl.classpath">
    <pathelement location="${env.ORACLE_HOME}/patch_wls1036/profiles/default/sys_manifest_classpath/weblogic_patch.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${env.ORACLE_HOME}/patch_ocp371/profiles/default/sys_manifest_classpath/weblogic_patch.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${env.JAVA_HOME}/lib/tools.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${env.ORACLE_HOME}/wlserver_10.3/server/lib/weblogic_sp.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${env.ORACLE_HOME}/wlserver_10.3/server/lib/weblogic.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${env.ORACLE_HOME}/modules/features/weblogic.server.modules_10.3.6.0.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${env.ORACLE_HOME}/wlserver_10.3/server/lib/webservices.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${env.ORACLE_HOME}/modules/org.apache.ant_1.7.1/lib/ant-all.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${env.ORACLE_HOME}/modules/net.sf.antcontrib_1.1.0.0_1-0b2/lib/ant-contrib.jar"/>
    <fileset dir="${env.ORACLE_HOME}/oracle_common/common/wlst/lib">
      <include name="*.jar"/>
    </fileset>
    <fileset dir="${env.ORACLE_HOME}/oracle_common/common/wlst/resources">
      <include name="*.jar"/>
    </fileset>
    <pathelement location="${env.ORACLE_HOME}/utils/config/10.3/config-launch.jar"/>
  </path>

  <target name="create_user">

    <taskdef name="wlst"
        classname="weblogic.ant.taskdefs.management.WLSTTask" classpathref="wl.classpath" />

    <wlst debug="true" failonerror="true" executeScriptBeforeFile="true" fileName="create_user.py">
      <classpath>
        <path refid="wl.classpath"/>
      </classpath>
    </wlst> 
  </target>    

</project>
```

create_user.py

```
from weblogic.management.utils import AlreadyExistsException

connect('weblogic', 'password', 't3://localhost:7001')
serverConfig()
authenticator = cmo.getSecurityConfiguration().getDefaultRealm().lookupAuthenticationProvider('DefaultAuthenticator')

try:
    print("Creating group.")
    authenticator.createGroup('groupName', 'groupDescription')
    print("Group created.")
except AlreadyExistsException:
    print("Ignoring group as it already exists.")
    pass

print("Creating user 'groupName'.")    
authenticator.createUser('userName', 'userPassword%!1', 'userDescription')

print("Addding user to group.")
authenticator.addMemberToGroup('groupName', 'userName') 

disconnect()
```